# how to set a theme to use ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-toolbar

i am trying to use ActionBar, i checked some postes, and i wrote the below code but at run time i receive the below logCat output. i know it is about the theme od the App, i tried to set a new theme as shown in the code below but it also it does not work.

please let mek now how to fix it.

**code**:

```
private void initActionBar() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.action_discover_title);
}
```

**style.xml**

```
<resources>
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
</resources>
```

**logcat**:

```
09-01 17:35:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19987): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 17:35:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19987): Process: com.example.ble_00, PID: 19987
09-01 17:35:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19987): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ble_00/com.example.ble_00.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
09-01 17:35:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2689)
09-01 17:35:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2754)
09-01 17:35:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19987):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
09-01 17:35:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19987):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
09-01 17:35:46.237: E/AndroidRuntime(19987):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you need a Appcompat theme to use ActionBar. Change the `parent="android:Theme.Light"` to any Appcompat theme as your look and feel preferences.
eg:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        can override the default look and feel of the parent theme
    -->
</style>
```

You can look more on Styling ActionBar [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html).

and use that theme to on your Activity that you want to use the Appcomapt. You can specify it in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/label"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

this :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>
```

should be :

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>
```